# Help to ID a Diode? I think

Tags: diodes, identification

[image][image: component photo]

Can anyone please help me to identify this? I’m not sure if it a Zener, Schottky, or rectifier.

It came off a board from a 12V camera. The camera is not getting power.

I thought it just look like a diode, couldn't find any info online..

Size: 0.235” x 0.272” x 0.100”.

Comment: i wrote b28d in Google and it looks like its transistor

Comment: What makes you think it is a diode? I do not see a clear marking on the case. Can you also post a picture of the PCB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing *exactly* how this component was part of the original circuit, would help confirm/deny some hypotheses - i.e. you reverse-engineer that part of the circuit.

> I’m not sure if it a Zener, Schottky, or rectifier.

I suspect none of them.

The marking **DEM** as seen on the photo, is used by some manufacturers for a 15V standoff bi-directional [TVS diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode) e.g. Littelfuse part number SMDJ15CA ([datasheet on the range](http://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smdj_datasheet.pdf.pdf), see page 2) although the component in the photo seems to be from a different manufacturer which I haven't identified. That hypothesis of it being a 15V TVS, would make sense for a 12V power input as you describe (with some voltage tolerance).

I *suspect* this component was directly across the input power rails. If you confirm that, it would strengthen the confidence in this identification.

TVS diodes are used to clamp voltage spikes. Devices don't require them to work normally. Since your camera doesn't work even after removing the TVS, then the TVS isn't the cause of your problem. Your camera's fault is elsewhere, unfortunately.